# Jquery - Read all Classes from a div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to read all class names from HTML element in the following way. But it doesn't work:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test" class="fff aaa ccc" >hello world</div>
```

**JS**

```
if ($('#test').attr('class') != '')
{
   // Read classes
    var all_classes = $('#test').attr('class');

    // Output
    $('body').append('Classnames: '+all_classes+' ');

}
```

**Example**
http://www.jsfiddle.net/AQgqU/8/

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I took our your `function()` and it worked fine (http://www.jsfiddle.net/AQgqU/10/). cc @rantanplan

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
var classes = $('#test').attr('class').split(' ');

alert(classes[0]); // first class
alert(classes[1]); // second class
alert(classes[2]); // third class
```

Or you can use a loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
  alert(classes[i]);
}
```

**Update:**

As suggested by @KennyTM, with above code there was possibility of space coming around a class name. You can use the `$.trim` function of jQuery to remove any space.

Comment: I think you should `$.trim()` it and split by `/\s+/`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function works fine, but you have a syntax error at the end:

```
$(function()
{

    // Has the #test a Class?
    if ($('#test').attr('class') != '')
    {
       // Read classes
        var all_classes = $('#test').attr('class');

        // Output
        $('body').append('Classnames: '+all_classes+' ');

    }


}):
//^ There's a colon just here, should be a semi-colon ;
```

here's your fixed fiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/AQgqU/12/