# How do I return multiple CSS classes with the .attr() method?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list where the list items have multiple CSS classes, such as:

```
<li class="nav-all active"><a href="#">All</a></li>
```

I'm trying to use jQuery to pull this info into a string on click:

```
var navButtons = $(".nav li");
navButtons.click(function() {
var category = $(this).attr('class');
//Do more stuff here
});
```

However, I'm only getting the first class back, as opposed to the full string, which would be `"nav-all active"` in this example. Is this the intended functionality? I don't see anything about this behavior in the API. Also, is there a way to modify the `.attr` call so that I get the full result or is `this.className` the only option here?

**Edit:** Thanks for the help, everyone. I based the sample code in this question on a larger script, which was dynamically applying the second class, and it turns out that I was calling `.attr` at a point when the `li` only had one class, so I was getting the correct result back. Seeing the fiddle shared by @Barmar helped me make the connection, so I guess the takeaway is to test smaller bits in isolation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - Read all Classes from a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802508/jquery-read-all-classes-from-a-div)

Comment: When I try it I get both classes. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ds3nhv7q/

Comment: @SimonMerrick The problem in that question turns out to be a typo in the fiddle. His code works when that's fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can just get it by using this.classList, that will return you an array like list.

```
var navButtons = $(".nav li");
navButtons.click(function() {
var category = this.classList;
category[0];// => "nav-all"
//Do more stuff here
});
```

More info on the tokenList https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList

Answer (score 0):

I would just split class like this:

```
 var category = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ds3nhv7q/1/)